# How do I send an already running process to the background in power shell?

Tags: powershell

In bash, a process that is already running in the foreground can be suspended by hitting control Z. You can then bring it back to the foreground with `fg` or let it continue running in the background with `bg`.

Is there a way to do this with power shell? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185575/powershell-equivalent-of-bash-ampersand-for-forking-running-background-proce) asks a related question for processes which haven't been started yet, but I want to know the answer for an already running process.

Comment: That isn't possible so far as I know. I just open a new tab in ConEmu if the current one is busy.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No

There's hope though: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3229

Comment: This issue was closed for inactivity. There is no more hope.

Comment: reopened on Nov 29, 2023. There's a new hope.

Answer (score 3):

You can't if you've launched your command directly.

*BUT*

You can do this (yes, it's an ugly trick) :

- Start your command in the background with :
  `Start-Job -ScriptBlock { <your_command> }`
- Then pull it on the foreground with `Receive-Job -Wait -Id <your_job_id>`

Now your Job is on the foreground.

- If you want to put it in the background, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>
- If you want to bring it to the foreground again, type again : `Receive-Job -Wait -Id <your_job_id>`

Answer (score -3):

You can use PowerShell job cmdlets to achieve your goals.

There are 6 job related cmdlets available in PowerShell.

- Get-Job

  - Gets Windows PowerShell background jobs that are running in the current session
- Receive-Job

  - Gets the results of the Windows PowerShell background jobs in the current session
- Remove-Job

  - Deletes a Windows PowerShell background job
- Start-Job

  - Starts a Windows PowerShell background job
- Stop-Job

  - Stops a Windows PowerShell background job
- Wait-Job

  - Suppresses the command prompt until one or all of the Windows PowerShell background jobs running in the session are complete

If interesting about it, you can download the sample [How to create background job in PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-create-background-b2a6a8ee)

Comment: While these may be helpful in some cases, they do not answer the question being asked. In OP's case (and in mine) he would like to send the job that is currently running to the background, without interrupting the job.